# Laravel storage/logs connected to absolute path

Tags: php, laravel

I want to deploy my laravel app to a webserver. I get the following error message:

```
is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/my/local/path/storage/logs) is not within the allowed path(s)
```

How could I set storage/logs to a relative path?

I ran

```
php artisan storage:link
```

It said:

```
The [/my/local/path/public/storage] link has been connected to [/my/local/path/storage/app/public].
The links have been created.
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try to change storage folder permission

```
chmod -R 755 storage
```

Comment: The permissions are right.
As the error message show, it search for the storage/logs in my local computer absolute path. I want to change it to search relative path in the server.